# SSL 404 Error with WordPress Multisite

Tags: php, wordpress, security, ssl, multisite

I just installed SSL on my DigitalOcean droplet, but when I try to view my pages over SSL, it returns a 404 error page. Viewing over normal http works just fine though. Any advice?

Comment: Are you sure you configured the SSL cert properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed it after, what felt like a lifetime of editing virtual host files.

```
DocumentRoot /Directory/of/Website/

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<Directory /Directory/of/Website/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

Change "none" in the "AllowOverride" lines to "all" in the Virtual Host config for port 443. Or whatever port you have SSL running on.

Answer (score -1):

How are you linking subsites together?

For SSL to work, you MUST have it signed to *.domain.com (this way you will get www.domain.com and also subsite.domain.com), and into your WPMU configs, you should use subdomain as routes.

Be extremely carefull when installing SSL, because I've seen many people losing it for configuring it directly with some subdomain.domain (like www)

Comment: So, is your SSL self-signed? See if it's pointing to the correct domain using wildcards...If you haven't seen it yet, here is a great path to follow step-by-step
http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Over_SSL